# equivalence relation - checking

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

At $\mathcal P(\mathbb{Z})$ we define equivalence relation $\equiv$ :

$A \equiv B \iff (A=B \vee (A \cup B)\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset)$

a)show that $\equiv$ is a equivalence relation at $\mathcal P({\mathbb{Z}})$

I'm not sure if it's proper but can I prove it using only one condition $A=B$ ? from it follows immediately that it's equivalence relation

b) find cardinality of equivalence classes

if $A \in \mathcal P(\mathbb{Z\setminus N})$ then $|[A]|=c$ since then from $A \equiv B \iff (A \cup B)\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$ we have $B \in \mathcal P(\mathbb{Z\setminus N})$ and $|\mathcal P(\mathbb{Z\setminus N})|=c$

if $A \not\in \mathcal P(\mathbb{Z\setminus N})$ we have only $A \equiv B \iff (A=B)$ so 
$|[A]|=1$ since it's only one set that $A=B$

c) find cardinality of quotient set $|Q|$

we have $A \subseteq \mathcal P(\mathbb{Z})$ so $|Q| \le c$ but if $A \neq B$ then $A$ and $B$ are at different equivalence classes so since $A \in \mathcal P(\mathbb{Z})$ then $|Q| \ge c $ so $|Q|=c$

are my reasoning correct ?

Comment: As for a) no you cannot not, for example $A = \{-1\}, B = \{-2\}, C = \{-3\}$ then we have $A \equiv B, B \equiv C$ but $A \neq B, B \neq C$ but we do have $A \equiv C$ and $A \neq C$, so just using the fact that $=$ is an equivalence relation does not suffice.

Comment: No, you must use the definition as it is, but that doesn't seems to  be difficult at all.

Comment: so I have to split it into two cases ? meaning to show that $A=B$ is equiv relation and $(A \cup B)\cap \mathbb{N}= \emptyset$ is as well ?

Comment: Your reaoning for part b looks OK, each equivalence class of $A$ is either of cardinality 1 (if $A$ has any natural numbers in it) or else $c$ since in that case the equivalence class of $A$ consists of all of the subsets of the negative integers.

Comment: to a) I mean if $A \in P(\mathbb{Z\setminus N})$ then we check that both conds holds otherwise we check that $A=B$ holds. Is it ok ?

Comment: @coffeemath what you think about c) ?

Comment: Mario: part (c) (about the cardinality of the quotient) looks more involved, at least initially. But the quotient set is at least of cardinality c since it contains each equivalence class of every set $A$ of integers having at least one natural number as an element. Such $A$ are singleton equivalence classes by the part (b) reasoning, and there are certainly a continuum of choices of these $A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first point, we have for all $A \in P(\mathbb{Z})$ $A\equiv A$ because $A=A$.

let $A, B \in P(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $A\equiv B$ so $(A=B \vee (A \cup B)\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset)$ and then $(B=A \vee (B \cup A)\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset)$ so $B\equiv A$.

Let $A, B, C \in P(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $A\equiv B$ and $B\equiv C$ we need to proof that $A \equiv C$ so we have two cases :

- If $A=B$ so $B\equiv C$ implies that $A\equiv C$.
- If $ (B \cup A)\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$ and $(B \cup C)\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$ so :

$$\emptyset =\emptyset\cup \emptyset =[(B \cup A)\cap\mathbb{N}] \cup [(B \cup C)\cap\mathbb{N}] =[(B \cup A\cup C)\cap\mathbb{N}] \supset (A\cup C)\cap\mathbb{N}$$
that mean  $(A\cup C)\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$ and so $A\equiv C$

For b) if we have $A\equiv B$ so we have two cases :

- If $ (B \cup A)\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$ so $B \cap \mathbb{N} = A \cap \mathbb{N}=\emptyset$ and that mean $A,B\in P(\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{N})$, and reciprocally if we have $A,B\in P(\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{N})$ that implies $(B \cup A)\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$. so we have our first class $P(\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{N})$, of cardinal $c$ as you say.
- If $A\not\in P(\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{N})$ so $A\cap \mathbb{N}\neq \emptyset$ so $A\equiv B$ if and only if $A=B$, so for each $A \not\in P(\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{N}) $ $A=[A]$ and so cardinal of $[A]$ is one in this case.

and for the last question I described all elements of $Q$ and we see that $P(\mathbb{N})\subset Q \subset P(\mathbb{Z})$ so $|Q|= c$

Comment: thanks, how about point c) ?

Comment: what that cardinal c mean in your proof of b) and c) ?

Comment: it means continuum

Comment: for your both answer are true, but your reasoning in b) isn't too good;

Comment: can you elaborate why?

Comment: excuse me you are right